# Why is Windows not displaying confirmation while deleting read only folders?

Tags: vb.net, directory

I have a folder `"I:\mydir"`, it is `read only`. Upon executing the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim subPath = "I:\mydir"
   Try
    Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath)
    Directory.Delete(subPath)
    Dim directoryExists = Directory.Exists("I:\mydir")
    Dim subDirectoryExists = Directory.Exists(subPath)
    Console.WriteLine("top-level directory exists: " & directoryExists)
    Console.WriteLine("sub-directory exists: " & subDirectoryExists)
   Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", ex.Message)
   End Try
  End Sub
```

The directory is removed without asking any confirmation message ("Are you sure you want to move this folder to recycle bin?").

I then denied all access privileges for the folder and executed the same code again. But this time it was not deleted. And an exception is thrown as `"access is denied"`.

So, why aren't any confirmation messages shown before deleting ordinary as well as read only directories?

Comment: You have to write the code that'll ask permission.

Comment: @ the_lotus : am not saying about vb_alert for confirmation: my question is that why windows(OS) is not showing the confirmation message

Comment: It is by throwing you an exception. Then you have to prompt the user yourself and ask them. Or do a check before trying to delete.

Comment: @ the+lotus : my question is **why the operating system not showing confirmation message** (**not How to show a confirmation message**) for deleting a folder from the hard disk. in normal case a folder or file is deleted only after confirmation.

Comment: The OS doesn't show a message, it's your job to do it. When you're using Windows Explorer, it's that application that shows the message, not the OS.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is deleting through System.IO, which requires you to do this type of stuff, if you want.  What you are looking for is under the My.Computer.FileSystem namespace. This example will send the file to the recycle bin with confirmation.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\temp\TestDelete.txt", FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)
```